# Get IIS to use .NET Framework > 4.6

Tags: iis, .net

I have a newly installed Win Server 2016 with "IIS 10" installed (by "add features"->/guide/--> tick install IIS")

When I look at my app pools I see that thay have ".NET CLR Version" 4.0 and my apps uses v4.6.x. I cant change to any other versions in the dropdown.

When I check the win-registry (using [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)) at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full

I get the number indicating .NET version 4.7. **So how do I upgrade my IIS/App pools to support .NET FW > 4.0?** This is a production server, so I dont want to start downloading and installing packages willy nilly here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIS and its App pools already support 4.7, there is nothing you need or can do about this.

Think of `.NET CLR Version 4.0` to actually mean `.NET CLR Version 4.x`, there is only a single CLR 4 installed on your machine and IIS is using it.

No need to do anything, your application should run fine.